# How to find string value is in exponential format in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, string, number-formatting, exponential

I want to find whether string has exponential format or not. Currently i am checking like below.

```
var s = "1.23E+04";
var hasExponential = s.Contains("E");
```

But i know this is not the proper way. So can anyone please guide proper and fastest way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: @GrantWinney, if it is in exponential form, i want to use another value from another variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you also want to make sure it really is a number, not just a string with an 'E' in it, maybe a function like this can be helpful.  The logic remains simple.

```
private bool IsExponentialFormat(string str)
{
    double dummy;
    return (str.Contains("E") || str.Contains("e")) && double.TryParse(str, out dummy);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use regular expression?

```
string s = "1.23E+04";
string pattern = @"^\d{1}.\d+(E\+)\d+$";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
bool hasExponential = rgx.IsMatch(s);
```

Comment: performance should be affected when we use Regex. So can you tell performance effective way?

Comment: @Selvamz Performance is always affected, don't reject this because you **think** it might impact your solution, which it probably won't.

Comment: @Bas This method performs twice as slow as the method by sstan, or the second method I mentioned.

Comment: @EBrown but as opposed to whatever algorithm is also running, it might be 0.001 or 0.002 of your total runtime

Comment: @Bas That's an irrelevant statement if the OP is concerned about performance. It doesn't matter *what portion* of the runtime it is, if the OP wants the fastest algorithm, this is **not** it.

Comment: Or the OP doesn't know that this part of perf doesn't matter, like 99% of OPs concerned about perf http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 0):

You could always split on `e`. Or use `double.TryParse`. Both work pretty well. (I would bet the `ParseExponential2` is faster for valid ones, whereas `ParseExponential1` **could** be faster for invalid ones.)

```
public static void _Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] exponentials = new string[] { "1.23E+4", "1.23E+04", "1.23e+4", "1.23", "1.23e+4e+4", "abce+def", "1.23E-04" };

    for (int i = 0; i < exponentials.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("Input: {0}; Result 1: {1}; Result 2: {2}; Result 3: {3}", exponentials[i], (ParseExponential1(exponentials[i]) ?? 0), (ParseExponential2(exponentials[i]) ?? 0), (ParseExponential3(exponentials[i]) ?? 0));
}

public static double? ParseExponential1(string input)
{
    if (input.Contains("e") || input.Contains("E"))
    {
        string[] inputSplit = input.Split(new char[] { 'e', 'E' });

        if (inputSplit.Length == 2) // If there were not two elements split out, it's an invalid exponential.
        {
            double left = 0;
            int right = 0;

            if (double.TryParse(inputSplit[0], out left) && int.TryParse(inputSplit[1], out right) // Parse the values
                && (left >= -5.0d && left <= 5.0d && right >= -324) // Check that the values are within the range of a double, this is the minimum.
                && (left >= -1.7d && left <= 1.7d && right <= 308)) // Check that the values are within the range of a double, this is the maximum.
            {
                double result = 0;

                if (double.TryParse(input, out result))
                    return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public static double? ParseExponential2(string input)
{
    if (input.Contains("e") || input.Contains("E"))
    {
        double result = 0;

        if (double.TryParse(input, out result))
            return result;
    }

    return null;
}

public static double? ParseExponential3(string input)
{
    double result = 0;

    if (double.TryParse(input, out result))
        return result;

    return null;
}
```

If the `ParseExponential1`, `ParseExponential2` or `ParseExponential3` returns `null`, then it was invalid. This also allows you to parse it at the same time and get the value indicated.

The only issue with `ParseExponential3` is that it will also return valid numbers if they are not exponential. (I.e., for the `1.23` case it will return `1.23`.)

You could also remove the checks for the `double` range. They are just there for completeness.

Also, to prove a point, I just ran a benchmark with the code below, and the `Regex` option in the other answer by nevermoi took `500ms` to run 100,000 times over the `exponentials` array, the `ParseExponential1` option took `547ms`, and the `ParseExponential2` option `317ms`. The method by sstan took `346ms`. Lastly, the fastest was my `ParseExponential3` method at `134ms`.

```
string[] exponentials = new string[] { "1.23E+4", "1.23E+04", "1.23e+4", "1.23", "1.23e+4e+4", "abce+def", "1.23E-04" };

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int round = 0; round < 100000; round++)
    for (int i = 0; i < exponentials.Length; i++)
        ParseExponential1(exponentials[i]);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Benchmark 1 (ParseExponential1) complete: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sw.Reset();

sw.Start();
for (int round = 0; round < 100000; round++)
    for (int i = 0; i < exponentials.Length; i++)
        ParseExponential2(exponentials[i]);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Benchmark 2 (ParseExponential2) complete: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
sw.Reset();
string pattern = @"^\d{1}.\d+(E\+)\d+$";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

sw.Start();
for (int round = 0; round < 100000; round++)
    for (int i = 0; i < exponentials.Length; i++)
        rgx.IsMatch(exponentials[i]);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Benchmark 3 (Regex Parse) complete: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
sw.Reset();

sw.Start();
for (int round = 0; round < 100000; round++)
    for (int i = 0; i < exponentials.Length; i++)
        IsExponentialFormat(exponentials[i]);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Benchmark 4 (IsExponentialFormat) complete: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sw.Start();
for (int round = 0; round < 100000; round++)
    for (int i = 0; i < exponentials.Length; i++)
        ParseExponential3(exponentials[i]);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Benchmark 5 (ParseExponential3) complete: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

And the following method was added:

```
private static bool IsExponentialFormat(string str)
{
    double dummy;
    return (str.Contains("E") || str.Contains("e")) && double.TryParse(str, out dummy);
}
```

Comment: `e-` and `E-` are valid too. That's the trouble with being too clever to gain a microsecond.  Simplicity ensures correctness, which should always be priority number one.

Comment: @sstan Ah yes, I forgot about the negatives. I'll make that change.

Comment: Plus, you are creating a bunch of new strings by splitting. Regex is much faster than that.

Comment: @Bas Have you benchmarked it? If not, then that statement is invalid. I just benckmarked it and the `Regex` option is the same speed as the string option, which is twice as slow as the non-string option.

Comment: Try with RegexOptions.Compiled

Comment: @Bas Even if you use `RegexOptions.Compiled` with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, it's still just as slow. If you remove `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` and replace `E` with `[Ee]`, it's still slower than the `double.TryParse` options. (Albeit not as slow as before, but still slower than any of the non-string/non-regex options.) You just can't squeeze the same performance out of a `Regex` like that. (Though, it *is* faster than my `string.Split` method with either of the `RegexOptions.Compiled` methods.)

Comment: @Bas I honestly don't care at this point, I have laid out the facts. Take them or leave them. I'm not going to argue with someone who is being pedantic about the situation. This isn't even *your* question and you're trying to be pedantic about it.